# Angular RouterModule : how to ignore path in proxy.conf.json?

Tags: angular

I'm looking to ignore a path (in this example `/backexample`) in my RouterModule which is present on my `proxy.conf.json` for calling my back api.

I'm using Angular 12.

This my `app-routing.module.ts` :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'view',
    component: ViewComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My `proxy.conf.json` :

```
"/backexample/public/api/v1/*" : {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080/",
    "pathRewrite": {"^/backexample": ""},
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": false
}
```

On localhost building, I don't encounter any problem during the call of my API ;
My `localhost:4200/backexample/blabla` browser call will succesfully pass the routing module without redirection.

However, after made a deployment with `ng build --configuration production` and when i'm trying the application on remote server :
My 'https://myfakeserver.com/backexample/blabla` request will throw this error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'backexample/blabla'
```

My `index.html` base href is set to '/'

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem ? And ignore the path `backexample` from my RouterModule ?

Regards

Comment: How do you deploy the application?

The `proxy.json` is meant to be used in development only. In the production you should configure the proxy on an nginx or another web server.

Comment: @StPaulis My apache 2 configuration have a Rewrite rule :
`ProxyPass /backexample https://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse /backexample https://localhost:8080 /backexample`

Comment: The problem should be there, this is not an Angular question, I would recommend you to open a new issue.

Comment: Are you sure ? I've just try to disable my RouterModule and it's work : my API correctly return data without the `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'backexample/blabla'`
But i really need my RouterModule 

Comment: What is happening is that you don't have a proxy in your backend for the path `/api/*`.
You don't have to make any changes on the Angular code. Only to create the same proxy that you have on development to production.

Comment: I have understood my error. I'm idiot. It was effectively my apache configuration. Thank's !

Comment: I have been there, it is normal to be confused by that. You are welcome!